# REST client in C++

Tags: c++, xml, rest, client

Has anybody successfully tried any C++ REST library (client) in their enterprise product? It can be collection of software stack, but it should have the capability to run on all platforms, i.e.: Windows, Linux, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX.

Comment: I've had plenty of success using libcurl against REST servers. Perhaps you could be more specific in your needs (support for default actions? support for different http keywords ? Supports deserialization of xml/json ?)

Comment: after looking into java REST client implementation here are few key support that are required.  HttpClient like support (like @Michael-O mentioned transport layer).  2. serialization support for XML (here i will prefer something which is having a good binding with schema - even though looks anti-REST) so that developers don't have to write xml parsers everywhere.  3. Not evaluated JSON support yet.

Answer (score 2):

[C++ REST SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) is an actively developed C++ REST client that is currently supported in Windows, Mac OS X, iOS and Android. It is also licensed under Apache License 2.0 which opens up a range of customizations on the library to suit your needs.

Comment: In 2021 **cpprestsdk is in maintenance mode and we do not recommend its use in new projects. We will continue to fix critical bugs and address security issues.**

Comment: How about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check thin REST client for C++ at https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp.

It is a C++ wrapper around good and stable multiprotocol, multiplatform [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list for most useful C++ libraries include network library:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

you can see listed can be used as REST client library:

1. Boost.Beast
2. C++ REST SDK
3. curlpp

Comment: For light weight usage, I am using [libcpr/cpr](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr) in [laoshanxi/app-mesh](https://github.com/laoshanxi/app-mesh) replaced cpprestsdk.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot recommend any integrated solution but what you can do is use:

1. Transport: neon, serf or libcurl (all of them have advs and disadvs)
2. XML parsing: libexpat or libxml2
3. JSON parsing: Jansson or JSON Spirit

Comment: Thanks @Michael-O but this is very crude stack to begin with (ie: it does all the job requred but still will need lot of boilerplate code to be implemented by the developer). What i am looking at something more in terms with java implementation of REST HttpClient (more like cassandra) but not tied to single platform.

Comment: I doubt that you will find something functionally similar to any Java-based client in C++. The second problem is that you want it portable the above libraries do other client maybe not or they depent ono the above.

Comment: agreed. looks like c++ is not having much mature lib to handle REST. I was curious on that in case some implementaion like gSOAP has been done. hope this thread will get better answers later.